# What is the difference between jmp and ja?

Tags: assembly, x86

From my understanding `jmp` does an unconditional jump, whereas `ja` jumps if the value is unsigned. Am I getting this right?

An example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be helpful [X86 Assembly/Control Flow](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow)

Comment: For anyone who wonders, `ja` stands for **j**ump if **a**bove.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct that `jmp` does an unconditional jump.

Your description of `ja` is incorrect, though. It does a conditional jump, based on the result of the most recent `cmp` operation. It jumps if the first operand was greater than the second operand, using unsigned comparison rather than signed comparison. `jg` would use signed comparison.

Comment: `ja` jumps based on the condition flags. The condition flags are set by `cmp` instructions but are also set by various other instructions, including simple arithmetic instructions such as `add`.

Answer (score 6):

`ja` means "jump if Carry Flag unset and Zero Flag unset".

The `cmp` instruction is really the same as the `sub` instruction (i.e. it subtracts its arguments), except that the result is not saved but only the condition flags are updated.

If we were comparing unsigned integers, subtracting `(a-b)` sets the Carry Flag if `b` is greater than `a`, and the Zero Flag if `b` is equal to `a`, so if neither of these flags is set, it follows that `a` is greater than `b`.

If we wanted a comparison of signed numbers, we'd have to compare the Sign Flag (i.e. the topmost bit of the result) to the Overflow Flag, and check that the Zero Flag is unset, which is what the `jg` instruction does.

Thus, the `cmp` instruction does not care about whether the arguments are signed or unsigned. This distinction is only in how the flags are interpreted afterwards.

[Source](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow)

Comment: ```If we were comparing unsigned integers, subtracting (a-b) sets the Carry Flag if b is greater than a, and the Zero Flag if b is equal to a, so if neither of these flags is set, it follows that a is greater than b```

I should be: if neither of these flags is set, it follows that a is smaller than b?